# Find out if string contains no words from a list. Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have the following piece of code:

```
for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("ft_mb_afterIteration", "FireTrailName", None, None):
...     if any(var in str(f[0]) for var in trails):
```

The second line checks if of the words from list "trails" are met in another string, str(f[0])

Now I need to reverse this and do something if none of the words from list "trails" are encountered in that string (str(f[0]).

What is the best way to do it? Are the any opposite expressions for 'any'?

Comment: ``not any`` would be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
if any(var in str(f[0]) for var in trails)
```

returns `True` if there is at least one word from trails is in `f[0]`.

```
if not any(var in str(f[0]) for var in trails):
```

returns `True` if there is no word is found in trails (which is what you want)

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Easy, but I am new :)))